# Convert downloaded mvt/pbf to new mbtiles file

Tags: mbtiles, pbf, tippecanoe, tileserver-gl

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Determine what pbf files are needed for a certain user-defined bbox (DONE)
2. Download these files for all zoomlevels. (DONE)
3. Combine these pbf files into a new mbtiles so I can serve it with tileserver-gl on an offline local network.

I managed step 1 and 2. So I end up with a directory structure with 14 zoom levels and all the necessary pbf files in /z/x/y.pbf structure. Now I want to repackage them into a mbtiles.

But I'm not sure how to continue with Step 3, without re-doing all the simplification etc tippecanoe or other converters normally do when creating a mbtiles from a vector dataset. I just want to put them in a mbtiles and recreate the necessary metadata. Any clues on that?